# What does "Attribute" mean in the ACE text file driver data type "LongChar Attribute 32"?

Tags: ms-access, jet, ms-jet-ace

For example, I'm looking at the following schema.ini:

```
[test.csv]
ColNameHeader=True
CharacterSet=1252
Format=CSVDelimited
Col1=JET1 Bit
Col2=JET2 Byte
Col3=JET3 Short
Col4=JET4 Integer
Col5=JET5 Currency
Col6=JET6 Single
Col7=JET7 Float
Col8=JET8 Date
Col9=JET9 LongChar Attribute 32
Col10=JET10 LongChar Attribute 32
Col11=ODBC1 Char Width 255
Col12=ODBC2 Float
Col13=ODBC3 Integer
Col14=ODBC4 LongChar Attribute 32
Col15=ODBC5 Date
```

generated by the following C#:

```
using System;
using System.Data.OleDb;

namespace Sandbox1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string ConnStr =
@"
Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;
Extended Properties=""Text;DATABASE=C:\Test""
";

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using (var conn = new OleDbConnection(ConnStr))
            using (var cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
            {
                conn.Open();
                cmd.CommandText =
@"
CREATE TABLE [test.csv]
  (
    JET1 BIT,
    JET2 BYTE,
    JET3 SHORT,
    JET4 LONG,
    JET5 CURRENCY,
    JET6 SINGLE,
    JET7 DOUBLE,
    JET8 DATETIME,
    JET9 TEXT,
    JET10 MEMO,
    ODBC1 CHAR,
    ODBC2 FLOAT,
    ODBC3 INTEGER,
    ODBC4 LONGCHAR,
    ODBC5 DATE
  )
";
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }

            //TestPossibleLimit(); // see below (in this SO Q)
        }
    }
}
```

which I wrote to explore what's described at the following MSDN page:

[Schema.ini File (Text File Driver)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms709353%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

The closest-seeming explanation I could find in the "Text File Driver Programming Considerations" docs is here:

[Text File Data Types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms715429%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

> LONGCHAR : The theoretical limit on the width of a LONGCHAR column in
>   either a fixed-length or delimited table is 65500K. The Text ISAM is
>   more likely to provide reliable support up to about 32K.

My thinking had been that the "Attribute 32" might indicate the number of kilobytes of text that's supported by the text file driver for the LONGCHAR data type, but I couldn't find any further information to confirm this.

So I threw in the following method to test that idea by inserting strings just shorter and just longer than this limit:

```
static void TestPossibleLimit()
{
    using (var conn = new OleDbConnection(ConnStr))
    using (var cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
    {
        conn.Open();

        var possibleLimit = 32 * 1024;
        for (var len = possibleLimit - 10;
             len <= possibleLimit + 10;
             ++len)
        {
            Console.Write("Inserting string of {0} 'x' characters...", len);

            cmd.CommandText = string.Format(
                "INSERT INTO [test.csv] (ODBC4) VALUES ('{0}')",
                new string('x', len));
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            Console.WriteLine(" Done!");
        }

        Console.WriteLine("All done!");
    }
}
```

The bad (or good?) news is that it worked fine---all output shown, no exceptions thrown, and the CSV reflects the insertions.

And so, since this Q's title has probably already scrolled out of your view:

**What does "Attribute" mean in the ACE text file driver data type "LongChar Attribute 32"?**

Note: Since I'm not entirely clear on the differences between ACE and Jet, I also tried the above code with the Jet 4 provider and got the same schema.ini and insertion behavior.